# python TypeError: list indices must be integers, not list

Tags: python

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not list
```

This is the problem child;

```
['19 16 7 197 161 127 38 28 18 180 119 90 202 124 102 215 151 116 255 235 208 252 216 192 244 208 174 84 36 26 193 158 126 170 118 81'] <type 'list'>
```

Printed to a file as a string. As you can see, its a list, composed of numbers, but not identified as integers. I get the error message when the data is set to the numpy module and the corrcoef() function.

If you can help me understand this, cool, and thank you.   gary

Things I have tried are :

```
a = [a**i for i in a1]
a = list(map(int,a1))
a = [a1[i] for i in a1]
a = [int(i) for i in a1]
```

Comment: At the end of the data string I put in type Id as the terminal displayed it <type 'list'>. gary

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite understand what you want to do with the given list, but if you want to convert it into a list of integers, you can do the following;

```
a = ['19 16 7 197 161 127 38 28 18 180 119 90 202 124 102 215 151 116 255 235 208 252 216 192 244 208 174 84 36 26 193 158 126 170 118 81']
a = map(int, a[0].split())
```

Comment: Or: `a = [ int(x) for x in a[0].split()]`

Answer (score 0):

So try this:

```
import re

a = re.findall(r'\d+', a[0]) # regex better for parsing more complex
```

Or try this:

```
a = [int(i) for i in a.split()] # a bit simpler in this scenario
```